# distributed/Parallel computing

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write application in .NET which will be make some calculations on few comuters (eg.3 computers). How write this application, wchich library i need to use. Do you now any good materials about that?

Comment: When it's homework then please mention that.

Comment: you can use wcf services on all the machines, and divide the task among them.

Comment: Sadly closed. Recommend you search Google for "distributed parallel computing for .NET". Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

Or if you really want to use multiple computers, then check out:

[Using Task Parallel Library with Multiple Computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866211/using-task-parallel-library-with-multiple-computers)